# Why show this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror, addeventlistener

I have some JavaScript code that gives this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
```

My code:

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
  <h1 id="our-heading">The page heading</h1> 
  <button id="button">Add Item</button>
  <ul id="our-list">
    <li>Item one</li>
    <li>Item two</li>
    <li>Item three</li>
    <li>Item four</li>
    <li>Item five</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var ourHeadline = document.getElementById("our-heading");
var listItems = document.getElementById("our-list").getElementsByTagName("li");

for (var i = 0; i<= listItems.length; i++){
    listItems[i].addEventListener("click", activateItem );
}

function activateItem(){
    ourHeadline.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
}
```

Please anyone give me the solution

Comment: Can you show the HTML?

Comment: Above the HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loop till the last item of array only, in your current code you are looping till the length of the array listItems

```
for (var i = 0; i<= listItems.length; i++){
    listItems[i].addEventListener("click", activateItem );
}
```

Since array index start for 0 , for the last iteration of the loop you will get the above mentioned undefined error due to the below code

```
listItems[i].addEventListener
```

change your code to

```
for (var i = 0; i< listItems.length; i++){
    listItems[i].addEventListener("click", activateItem );
}
```

Comment: Thank you problem is solved.

Comment: @ABSiddik you are welcome :)